# Предмет для битья ковров

Tags: названия

Чем выбивают пыль, стуча по ковру, каким приспособлением?

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [**Выбивалка для ковров**, иногда **хлопушка для ковров**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2) —
>   предмет домашнего обихода, предназначенный для чистки ковров.
>   Выбивалка напоминает по форме теннисную ракетку и изготавливается из
>   твёрдого пластика, металла или плетёного ротанга.

Возможны варианты, например - колотушка:

> A **carpet beater** or carpetbeater (also referred to as a rug beater
>   or rugbeater, carpet whip, rug whip, clothes-beater, dust beater or
>   dustbeater, carpet duster, wicker slapper, rug duster, or pillow
>   fluffer, and formerly also as a carpet cleaner or rug cleaner) is a
>   housecleaning tool used beat the carpets with it in order to shake
>   dust and dirt out of carpets. It was in common use until the vacuum
>   cleaner became widely affordable.

Варианты обратных переводов:

[**Ролл для ковров**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%91%D7%98_%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D) - это инструмент, который используется для чистки ковров от пыли.

> **Ковровые биты** обычно делались из бамбуковой ткани, но современные биты также изготавливались из пластика. Форма ролла для коврика
>   напоминает теннисную ракетку с длинной ручкой и в конце поверхности
>   петли. С годами использование **ковровых бамперов** уменьшилось в
>   пользу использования пылесосов.
>
> ---

---

И снова в  Россию...

[Житель Сосновоборска отшлепал падчерицу выбивалкой для ковров](https://www.penzainform.ru/news/life/2013/04/12/zhitel_sosnovoborska_otshlepal_padcheritcu_vibivalkoj_dlya_kovrov.html)

> ...Суд признал жителя Сосновоборска виновным в нанесении побоев
>   несовершеннолетней.
>
> Февральским вечером он поссорился с пятнадцатилетней дочерью своей
>   жены и нанес девочке металлической хлопушкой для выбивания ковров не
>   менее одного удара по голове и не менее двух ударов по спине...

Итого: хлопушка и выбивалка.